# Return statment not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

the function below is part of a node.js program that i am writing.

```
 var getDataFromUrl = function(url) {
    rest.get(url).on('complete',function(data) {
        if(data instanceof Error) {
            console.log("url error");
            process.exit(1);
        }else {return data}

        };
    });
};
```

this function downloads a webpage and returns it content but when i call
it in the program it return undefined. how do i solve this problem 
by the way when called on it own it works fine

Comment: There is no `return` statement in the code you posted.

Comment: There is no `return`, and there should not be. Whatever you need to do, do it from your `complete` callback.

Comment: @thiago.lenz good that means I'm not blind or crazy :)

Comment: @Pointy Well not blind sure, but the crazy? I'm not sold yet.

Comment: @bfavaretto, unless I'm totally off I'm pretty sure `complete` isn't a callback. Its saying basically: `on completing the get action do this anonymous function`.

Comment: Can you share with us the function calling your `getDataFromUrl`? I think we need that before we can give you a proper answer.

Comment: @ryan Right, it looks like an event handler. My point is, it is an asynchronous operation, so forget `return`.

Comment: i have realize that in node function that takes long is send to the background and the program continues. so now the question is how do i stop the execution of the program until the function returns

Comment: @user2398709 Don't do that, it's not the node way. Use the data from your `else`.

Comment: so all code for processing the data should go into the else statment?

Comment: Yes, or create a function to process the data, and pass it the data from the else.

Answer (score 0):

After careful research i realized that this function is an asynchronous operation and so will
program execution will continue whiles the function function runs in the background.

to solve this problem put all the code need to process the data been return right in the else
statement